# Filter string in Python

Tags: python, string

I managed to read out the current position data of a robot by using TCP/IP in a python application. This is performed every 0.08 seconds (80ms). See **code** below.

```
import urllib.request
import time
i = 0

while(i < 100):
    t0 = time.time()
    response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.41.110/MD/CURPOS.DG")

    for line_number, line in enumerate(response):
        if(line_number >= 165 and line_number <= 171):
            print(line)
    i = i + 1
    t1 = time.time()
    total = t1-t0
    print ("Total Cyclic time: ", total)
    print("\n\n")
```

**Output:**

```
b'X:    566.13\n'
b'Y:    226.40\n'
b'Z:    312.07\n'
b'W:    179.99\n'
b'P:       .00\n'
b'R:    -66.34\n'
Total Cyclic time:  0.07909107208251953
```

I want to save every axis: XYZ WPR inside of a variable. To achieve this, I want to filter the unnecessary information. There must be a simple solution to do this!

**Wanted Output:**

```
566.13
226.40
312.07
179.99
.00
-66.34
Total Cyclic time:  0.07909107208251953
```

Comment: I can't see any unnecessary information. Do you mean there can be some other information that comes in?

Comment: I believe he just wants the value and get rid of the rest... Decode thestring first. By finding the pos of ':' and '\' and then strip() + float() the value in between he should have what he wants.

Comment: How does the end result should be like?

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: For floating point numbers, do `print(float(line.split()[-1]))`; for strings, do `print(line.decode().split()[-1])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourvar = float((yourstring.decode("utf-8")[2:-1]).strip())
```

Comment: This does the job fine! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should decode the result since they're all bytes.
After you do that, you could just check if starting character is an X, a Y or a Z, and then strip the letter, the colon and the trailing \n to obtain the actual value.